$\int_{x_i>0} f(x_1+x_2, x_3+x_4)^* f(x_1+x_3, x_2+x_4) \geq0$ for any function $f$?
Let $f(u,v)$ be a "nice" complex-valued function defined on the region $u,v\geq 0$, e.g., $f$ is continuous and decays rapidly at infinity.
Problem: For any such function $f$, prove that
$$\int_{[0,\infty)^4} dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4 \:  f(x_1+x_2, x_3+x_4)^* f(x_1+x_3, x_2+x_4) \geq0.$$
Here the asterisk denotes the complex conjugation. The variables are "twisted" in $f^*$ and $f$.
Motivation: This problem is motivated from physics. By a physical argument, a certain quantity must be non-negative, and I found that it can be represented as an integral in the above form.
Note: One may assume that $f$ is symmetric, i.e., $f(u,v) = f(v,u)$. To see this, note that a generic function $f$ can be written as $f = f_s + f_a$, the sum of the symmetric and antisymmetic component. Enough to show that, e.g.,
$$A := \int f_s(x_1+x_2, x_3+x_4)^* f_a(x_1+x_3, x_2+x_4) =0$$
and
$$\int f_a(x_1+x_2, x_3+x_4)^* f_a(x_1+x_3, x_2+x_4) =0.$$
As an example, we prove the first equality. By changing the variables $x_1\leftrightarrow x_2$ and $x_3 \leftrightarrow x_4$, we obtain
$$A = \int f_s(x_1+x_2, x_3+x_4)^* f_a(x_2+x_4, x_1+x_3) = -A$$
by the antisymmetry $f_a(x_2+x_4, x_1+x_3) = - f_a(x_1+x_3, x_2+x_4)$. This implies $A=0$.

With the substitution $x_2\leftrightarrow x_3$ one can show that the integral is real-valued, and that it suffices to prove the statement for real-valued functions $f$. But I don't yet see why the integral is nonnegative.

@MartinR Thanks for your comment! It is a nice and simple observation that guarantees that "$\geq 0$" makes sense.

We consider the change of variables to $x_1, a, b, y$, where
$$a = x_1 + x_2, b = x_1 + x_3, y = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4.$$
The Jacobian of this change of variable is $1$. The inverse of this change of variables is
$$x_2 = a - x_1, x_3 = b - x_1, x_4 = y - a - b + x_1.$$
So the region $[0, \infty)^4$ is mapped to the new region
$$R = \{(x_1, a, b, y): \max(0, a + b - y) \leq x_1 \leq \min(a, b)\}.$$
And
$$\int_{[0,\infty)^4} dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4 \:  f(x_1+x_2, x_3+x_4)^* f(x_1+x_3, x_2+x_4)$$
is equal to
$$\int_{R} dx_1da db dy \:  f(a, y - a)^* f(b, y - b).$$
Now we can integrate in $x_1$. For each $a,b,y$ for which there is a satisfying $x_1$, the length of the integral in $x_1$ is
$$\min(a, b) - \max(0, a + b - y) = \min(a, b, y - a, y - b).$$
So the integral is equal to
$$\int_{[0,\infty)^3} da db dy \:  \max(0, \min(a, b, y - a, y - b)) f(a, y - a)^* f(b, y - b).$$
Now it is familiar that
$$\max(0, \min(a, b, y - a, y - b)) = \int_0^{\min(a, b, y - a, y - b)} dx$$
where we define the RHS to be $0$ if $\min(a, b, y - a, y - b) < 0$. So the integral becomes
$$\int_{[0,\infty)^3} da db dy \:  \int_0^{\min(a, b, y - a, y - b)} dx f(a, y - a)^* f(b, y - b).$$
Now we swap the order of integration so the $x$ variable is integrated first. If we set $R'(x)$ to be
$$\{(a,b,y): a \geq x, b \geq x, y - a \geq x, y - b \geq x\}$$
then the integral is equal to
$$\int_{[0, \infty)} dx \int_{R'(x)} da db dy \:  f(a, y - a)^* f(b, y - b).$$
The inner integral decouples into
$$\int_{R'(x)} da db dy \:  f(a, y - a)^* f(b, y - b) = \int_{2x}^\infty dy \left\vert \int_{x}^{y - x} da f(a, y - a)\right\vert^2$$
and the non-negativity of the integral follows.

I agree with your computation, but I don't see where the error in my computation is. My $R'(x)$ is not just a slice of $R$; it is the slice of $R$ shifted downward. I have added a few more steps to account for this. So I did some processing and made the integration region a square.

I gave some more comments below, you have an opinion on that? By the way, positivity of your last integral is a little too strong, nonnegativity would be fine. Indeed, as an example, for a function $f(u,v) = (u-v)\exp (-(u+v))$, the integral can be explicitely evaluated to be  zero.

Thanks for a very nice solution! I would like to ask a generalization of this question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4924215/int-x-i0-fx-1x-2-x-3x-4-fx-1x-3-x-2x-4-x-1x-2x-3x-4-alpha .

Too long for a comment on  the post of @abacaba, hence this post.
Let's integrate  directly from the equations which describe the change of variables.
Consider first $x_1$ as independent. Then, since $x_2 \ge 0$ and $x_3 \ge 0$, we have $a \ge x_1$ and $b \ge x_1$. Now, as $x_4 = y - a - b + x_1 \ge 0$, we get $y \ge a + b - x_1 \ge x_1$. Now, consider $y$ as independent as well. Then, again as $x_4 = y - a - b + x_1 \ge 0$, we get $a + b \le  x_1 + y$. So in total, the integral  reads
$$
\int_{[0, \infty)} dx_1 \int_{x_1}^\infty dy \int \int_{a \ge x_1, b\ge x_1, a + b \le  x_1 + y} da  d b f(a, y - a)^* f(b, y - b)
$$
The innermost double integral  does not automatically factorize and hence does not transform into an absolute square. Instead, its integration area is triangular.  We may as well write, making  the triangular integration explicit:
$$
I_1 = \int_{[0, \infty)} dx \int_{x}^\infty dy \int_{x}^{y}  da   f(a, y - a)^* \int_{x}^{x + y - a}  d b f(b, y - b)
$$
Note that $x$ in here has the meaning of $x_1$, whereas in the post of @abacaba it is introduced as the measuring variable for the length of the integral in $x_1$ with satisfying condition for each $a,b,y$. Anyway, since one may see integration variables as auxiliary, we have equality of $I_1$ presented above, with the result of  @abacaba,
$$
I_2 = \int_{[0, \infty)} dx 
\int_{2x}^\infty dy \left\vert \int_{x}^{y - x} da f(a, y - a)\right\vert^2
$$
which in itself is quite remarkable. Exemplary verification holds with some test functions which were deliberately chosen neither symmetric nor antisymmetric.
It would be interesting to see a direct verification for $I_1 = I_2$ without the "detour" over defining $x$ either as $x_1$ or as the measuring variable for the length of an integral, I did not manage  to get it. Anybody?
