$\int_{x_i>0} f(x_1+x_2, x_3+x_4)^* f(x_1+x_3, x_2+x_4) \;(x_1x_2x_3x_4)^\alpha \geq0$ for any function $f$ and $\alpha >-1$?
Let $f(u,v)$ be a "nice" complex-valued function defined on the region $u,v\geq 0$, e.g., $f$ is continuous and decays rapidly at infinity.
Problem: For any such function $f$ and for any $\alpha>-1$, prove that
$$\int_{[0,\infty)^4} dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4 \:  f(x_1+x_2, x_3+x_4)^* f(x_1+x_3, x_2+x_4)  \;(x_1x_2x_3x_4)^\alpha \geq0.$$
Here the asterisk denotes the complex conjugation. The variables are "twisted" in $f^*$ and $f$.
Motivation: This problem is motivated from physics. A physical argument implies that a certain quantity must be non-negative, and this quantity is represented as the above integral.
Note: In the special case $\alpha=0$, this problem is solved in $\int_{x_i>0} f(x_1+x_2, x_3+x_4)^* f(x_1+x_3, x_2+x_4) \geq0$ for any function $f$?. Here I outline the proof. We change the variables to $x_1, a,b,y$, where
$$a=x_1+x_2, \; b= x_1+x_3, \; y =x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4.$$
And we make a further change $\tilde x_1 = x_1 - \max\{0,a+b-y\}$ (this $\tilde x_1$ was denoted as $x$ in the linked solution). Then, in terms of the new variables $\tilde x_1, a,b,y$, the above integral becomes
$$\int_0^\infty d\tilde x_1 \int_{2\tilde x_1}^\infty dy \left[ \int_{\tilde x_1}^{y-\tilde x_1} da \: f(a,y-a) \right]^* \left[ \int_{\tilde x_1}^{y-\tilde x_1} db \: f(b,y-b) \right] \geq 0.$$
This proof relies on the fact that under a certain variable transformation, the integral over $a$ and $b$ factorizes, and are related each other by complex conjugation. However, in the case of general $\alpha$, the additional term $(x_1x_2x_3x_4)^\alpha$ becomes a non-factorized form after the variable transformation.

I think this is a very interesting question, and I think after the bounty expires you should ask it on mathoverflow

@pie Thanks for your interest and suggestion!

With some constant $c$ which is later to be determined, define for $(i = 1 \cdots 4)$ new variables $y_i = x_i^{1+c}$ and let $\beta = 1 + c$. We require $\beta > 0$ (which will be substantiated below).
Then $d y_i = (1+c) x_i^{c} d x_i$ and the integral becomes
$$\int_{[0,\infty)^4} dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4 \:  f(x_1+x_2, x_3+x_4)^* f(x_1+x_3, x_2+x_4)  \;(x_1x_2x_3x_4)^\alpha \\
= \frac{1}{\beta^4}\int_{[0,\infty)^4} dy_1dy_2dy_3dy_4 \:  f(y^{\beta}_1+y^{\beta}_2, y^{\beta}_3+y^{\beta}_4)^* f(y^{\beta}_1+y^{\beta}_3, y^{\beta}_2+y^{\beta}_4)   (x_1x_2x_3x_4)^{\alpha - c} $$
Since we are only interested in nonnegativity, here and in the following we ignore the factor $\frac{1}{\beta^4}$ and other positive prefactors.
The variables in $x_i$ are understood implicitely defined at $x_i = y_i^{1/\beta}$ which will be discussed later.
We consider another change of variables to $a, b, y, z$, where
$$a = y^{\beta}_1 + y^{\beta}_2, b = y^{\beta}_1 + y^{\beta}_3, y = y^{\beta}_1 + y^{\beta}_2 + y^{\beta}_3 + y^{\beta}_4, z = y_1^\beta.$$
The inverse of this change of variables is
$$y_1 = z^{1/\beta}, y_2 = (a - z)^{1/\beta},y_3 = (b - z)^{1/\beta}, 
y_4 = (y - a - b + z)^{1/\beta}.$$
The Jacobian $|\partial y_i / \partial a_i |$ is $J = (y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4)^{1 - \beta} \times 1/\beta^4 = (x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4)^{(1 + c)(- c)} \times 1/\beta^4 $
Again, since we are only interested in nonnegativity,  we ignore positive prefactors.
We examine the boundaries of the integration region for $\beta > 0$ (which will be substantiated below). Since $y_2 \ge 0$, we have $z = a - y^{\beta}_2 \le a$, likewise $z = b - y^{\beta}_3 \le b$, hence $z \leq \min(a, b)$. Further, since $z \ge 0$ and $y_4 \ge 0$, we have $z = y^{\beta}_4 + a+ b - y \ge \max(0, a + b - y)$.
So the region $[0, \infty)^4$ is mapped to the new region
$$R = \{(z, a, b, y): \max(0, a + b - y) \leq z \leq \min(a, b)).$$
And
$$\int_{[0,\infty)^4} dy_1dy_2dy_3dy_4 \:  f(y^{\beta}_1+y^{\beta}_2, y^{\beta}_3+y^{\beta}_4)^* f(y^{\beta}_1+y^{\beta}_3, y^{\beta}_2+y^{\beta}_4) (x_1x_2x_3x_4)^{\alpha - c}$$
is equal to
$$\frac{1}{\beta^4}  \int_{R} da db dy dz \:  (x_1x_2x_3x_4)^{\alpha - c - c (1 + c)} f(a, y - a)^* f(b, y - b).$$
Now the constant $c$ can be freely chosen. We let $\alpha - c - c (1 + c) = 0 $ which results in the choice  $c = -1 + \sqrt{1 + \alpha}\; $. Since $\alpha > -1$ according to the task, $c$ is real and   $\; \beta = \sqrt{1 + \alpha} > 0$. For $\alpha = 0$, we have $c=0$ hence  nothing needs to be done.
With this choice of $c$, we have to establish
$$\int_{R} da db dy dz \:   f(a, y - a)^* f(b, y - b) \ge 0.$$
Now this statement has already been proved in this post , so for completeness and self-sustained reading the following is given as a rephrasing from the quoted source:
For each $a,b,y$ for which there is a satisfying $z$ in the region $R$, the length $L_1$ of the integral in $z$ is $L_1 = \min(a, b) - \max(0, a + b - y)$. Considering the two cases $a \le b$ and $b \le a$ this can be simplified to
$$
L_1 = \min(a, b, y-a, y-b) 
$$
So the integral is equal to
$$\int_{[0,\infty)^3} da db dy \:  \max(0, \min(a, b, y - a, y - b)) f(a, y - a)^* f(b, y - b).$$
Now it is familiar that
$$\max(0, \min(a, b, y - a, y - b)) = \int_0^{\min(a, b, y - a, y - b)} dx$$
where we define the RHS to be $0$ if $\min(a, b, y - a, y - b) < 0$. So the integral becomes
$$\int_{[0,\infty)^3} da db dy \:  \int_0^{\min(a, b, y - a, y - b)} dx f(a, y - a)^* f(b, y - b).$$
Now we swap the order of integration so the $x$ variable is integrated first. If we set $R'(x)$ to be
$$\{(a,b,y): a \geq x, b \geq x, y - a \geq x, y - b \geq x\}$$
then the integral is equal to
$$\int_{[0, \infty)} dx \int_{R'(x)} da db dy \:  f(a, y - a)^* f(b, y - b).$$
The inner integral decouples and this becomes
$$ \int_{[0, \infty)} dx \int_{2x}^\infty dy \left\vert \int_{x}^{y - x} da f(a, y - a)\right\vert^2$$
and the non-negativity of the integral follows.

Thanks for an amazing answer! The trick was to reduce to $\alpha=0$ case by variable substitution.
